How to disable line break because of enter, shift+enter, cntrl+enter in TIp tap editor
I am using Tip tap editor for my project, I am able to disable the action performed by Enter button for my editor, but I need help for disabling the action for my Shift+Enter click
const DisableEnter = Extension.create({
        addKeyboardShortcuts() {
          return {
            Enter: () => {
              console.log('Enter pressed');
              return true;
            },
            'Shift-Enter': () => {
              console.log('Shiftkey disabled');

              return true; 
            },
            D: () => {
              return true;
            },
          };
        },
      });

then I placed the DisableEnter in my extensions, I am able to disable the Enter, but I try for shift enter, it does not work, though it works to not allow D as well, what can I do, i want a similar action for ctrl Enter
but it works if I do like this:
editorProps: {
                
                handleDOMEvents: {
                    keydown: (_, event) => {
                        if (event.shiftKey === true) {
                            if(event.key=="Enter") {
                                return true;
                            } 
                        }
                    },
                },
            },

So my question is can I do it using the extensions or the only option is through the editor props?
